# Increasing instanciation time of DynamicComponentLoader with increasing number of components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I noticed that instanciating multiple components on-demand using the `DynamicComponentLoader` results in an increasing time for every instance.

I modified a plunker to demonstrate this: http://plnkr.co/edit/h9IrZXFmLgNuWm9sYrJF

Inserting...

- 1 instance = ~2.54ms for each instance
- 10 instance = ~15.38ms for each instance
- 100 instance = ~75.76ms for each instance
- 1000 instance = ~460.01ms for each instance

I also discovered that the intialization is getting faster over time, e.g. when inserting 1000 instances the time ranges from 472.01ms for the first component to 449.88ms for the last component.

Tested in Firefox 45 and Angular 2 beta.9.

**Questions**

- Why is instanciation time for the same component not equal?
- How can I optimize the instanciation?